# Unresolved reference: BR (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding

My top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

My project level build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

I also added `android.databinding.enableV2=true` to gradle.properties per Google documents (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start)

When I try to run, it shows `Unresolved reference: BR` error in my `BaseViewHolder` class. It seems that `BR` class has been properly generated  but it also says duplicate class found in the file `.../R.java` when I mouse over the class name. What have I done wrong?

```
fun bind(obj: Any) {
        binding.setVariable(BR.obj, obj)
        binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After researching quite a bit, turns out there are a couple things to add in order to use data binding library

#### project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compiler_version = '3.1.3'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$compiler_version"
    }
}
```

#### app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$compiler_version"
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I started to have some warnings after adding the data binding library, like `3rd-party Gradle plug-ins may be the cause` and `Classpath entry points to a non-existent location`. But compiles and runs fine

Comment: I use AS3.2 beta4, kapt dependency is not required explicitly. If anyone have error about `DataBindingComponent', just delete the kapt dependency line, it works for me.

Comment: I have tested it with `Android Studio 3.3, Gradle 3.3.0, Databinding v2` and I can confirm what @Lyle commented, the *only* line that needs to be added to avoid the `Unresolved reference: BR` is `apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"`

Comment: It doesn't work for gradle version 4.2.2

Answer (score 59):

For Android Studio 3.3, Gradle 3.3.0 and Databinding v2, the only line that needs to be added to fix this issue is in your (app's or modules) `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"
```

Comment: For me (AS 4.2.1, Gradle 4.2.1) I had to add it to `plugins{}`: `plugins { id 'com.android.application' id 'kotlin-android' id 'kotlin-kapt' }`

Answer (score 45):

Android Studio failed to import my BR class automatically. All solutions provided above failed. I just had to import the class manually, Android studio had created it correctly.

SAMPLE:

```
package your_packagename

import your_packagename.BR
import ...
...
```

I think this happened due to Copy and Paste. When i typed `BR` manually, Android Stdio did the Automatic Import.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who faces this issue in Android Studio Chipmunk or above:

**First**
add this in the App level Gradle to enable data binding. This is the obvious one but making sure just in case.

```
buildFeatures {
       dataBinding true
   }
```

**Secondly** add kotlin-kapt plugin in the App level Gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

BR class is generated but not referenced properly that is why Unresolved Reference is coming. By adding kotlin-kapt, it will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I manually typed the line "binding.setVariable(BR.item, item)" and it worked for me. Android studio shows the suggestion of importing BR. Choose the one from your project. Also enable databinding = true in gradle.