# @Bindable doesn't generate a field in the BR class

Tags: android, android-databinding

I need to be notified when a field changed.
according to android documentation, Bindable annotation will generate a field in the BR class. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/Bindable)
but after assigning a @Bindable annotation to a field, I see no field created for that in BR class.

I clean and rebuild the project. but no advantage.
even I do invalidate cache and Restart. but nothing

this is my java class

```
class Job : BaseObservable(), Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: Int = 0

    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String = ""

    @SerializedName("is_requested")
    var isRequested: Boolean = false
        @Bindable get
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.requested)
        }

}
```

but I have error. BR.requested is unknown...

and this is mr BR class that automatically generated

```
public class BR {
  public static final int _all = 0;

  public static final int company = 1;

  public static final int jobExperience = 2;

  public static final int job = 3;

  public static final int educationHistory = 4;

  public static final int user = 5;

  public static final int userLanguage = 6;
}
```

as you see, there is no corresponding field for isRequested field of Job.kt in BR class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to apply the `kotlin-kapt` plugin.

This answer might be helpful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54197326/1944237

Comment: Very Very Tnx my friend.......... finally solved this problem for me...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
 @SerializedName("is_requested")
  var isRequested: Boolean = false
  @Bindable get
```

To :

```
 @SerializedName("is_requested")
var isRequested: Boolean
    @Bindable get() = isRequested
    set(value) {
        isRequested = value
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isRequested)
    }
```

No need for set and get method required. you can access it by default.

Comment: TNX a lot, but I need to setter and getter for that field to notify when changed. but after putting setter and getter, corresponding field with that doesn't create  in BR class.

Comment: it will create after successful build. don't worry it will work.

Comment: @MohammadSeyyedi i edit my post..please check and let me know its working or not.

Comment: no brother. it doesn't work yet. the field BR.isRequested is unknown for compiler...

Comment: do it delete build folder , clean and rebuild it again.