# Kotlin MVVM/Databinding gives me error 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

New to Kotlin here so bear with me. I've started with the default Kotlin application using fragments in Android studio. I've followed the databinding tutorial from [here](https://medium.com/@b.chandrasaimohan/data-binding-kotlin-login-screen-using-mvvm-6274979f4b83), but also numerous other tutorials in short: I've enabled databinding in my build.gradle, created a POJO extending BaseObservable (called RestClientSettings) and switched my tools fragment to databinding layout:

...

```
<data class="ToolsBinding">
    <variable name="model" type="com.example.tpm.ui.tools.RestClientSettings" />
    <variable name="viewModel" type="com.example.tpm.ui.tools.ToolsViewModel"/>
</data>
```

...

with an EditText which is using the 'host' property from my model:

...

```
    <EditText
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/edit_host"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="@={model.host}"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="187dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp" />
```

...

finally in my ToolsFragment:OnCreate I'm using the DataBinding util

...

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val toolBinder : ToolsBinding  = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_tools,container,false)
    return toolBinder.root
}
```

...

And here's the RestClientSettings class:
...

```
    package com.example.tpm.ui.tools

    import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable
    import androidx.databinding.Bindable
    import com.example.tpm.BR

    class RestClientSettings : BaseObservable() {

      var host: String = "0.0.0.0"
      @Bindable get() = field
      set(host) {
        field = host
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.host)
      }

      var port: Int = 8080
      @Bindable get() = field
      set(port) {
        field = port
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.port)
      }
    }
```

...

so far so good, but I'm getting the following error:
"*"*Unresolved reference: BR*" in the RestClientSettings class and 
"*Cannot resolve symbol host*" in my ToolsBindingImpl, in the onChageModel function: "*else if (fieldId == BR.host)*".

What I also notice, and what's probably the real problem, is at the top of the ToolsBindingImpl class, where it tries to inherit from ToolsBinding "*public class ToolsBindingImpl extends ToolsBinding*", I get the error: "*Cannot inherit from final 'com.example.tpm.databinding.ToolsBinding'*"

What am I missing here?

Comment: are at class RestClientSettings have a variable host ex.
`class RestClientSettings : BaseObservable() {
    var host: String? = null
        @Bindable get() = field
        set(host) {
            field = host
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.host)
        }
}`

Comment: I added the RestClientSettings class to my original question.

Comment: Try Change this `set(userName) {
        field = userName
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.host)
      }` to 'set(host) {
        field = host
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.host)
      }'

Comment: Fixed the typo (copy/paste error), but still the same errors.

Comment: After im check your reference tutorial this maybe at build.gradle in kotlin check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956111/unresolved-reference-br-android-studio hope this help

Comment: No still the same errors. Only a new warning: "w: [kapt] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding (DYNAMIC)."

Comment: i'm so sorry about that, I tried to find out about the problem, can you try to change RestClientSettings class from `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.host)` to `notifyPropertyChanged`(model.host)` hope this help